# How to replace n occurrences in file using sed?

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I am working on shell scripting and automation,i want to fulfil cetain tasks without writing more code.

below is sample xml of web service, i want to hit below request (Data.xml) with changing startdate in each segment.

mean in first invocation, only startdate of First tag will be modified and remaining startdate will be unchanged and so on.

my approach was removing all newlines and form entire xml in one line, then replace desired occurrence using sed.

i tried using below command

```
cat Data.xml | awk '{ print $1}'| xargs  echo | sed 's/<startdate>01011970<\/startdate>/<startdate>01011979<\/startdate>/2' | sed 's/> </>\n</g'
```

Output:

```
<Data>
<First>
<Name>Micheal</Name>
<Account-Validation>
<startdate>01011970</startdate>
<enddate>01019999</enddate>
</Account-Validation>
</First>
<Second>
<Name>Adam</Name>
<Account-Validation>
<startdate>01011979</startdate>
<enddate>01019999</enddate>
</Account-Validation>
</Second>
<Third>
<Name>Raul</Name>
<Account-Validation>
<startdate>01011970</startdate>
<enddate>01019999</enddate>
</Account-Validation>
</Third>
</Data>
```

the only issue which i see is it changes entire xml format. so i am looking for doing the same using hold buffer and pattern buffer approach.
here is sample command,

```
cat Data.xml | sed  '{/<Second>/,/<\/Second>/g;s/<startdate>01011970<\/startdate>/<startdate>01011979<\/startdate>/p};h;
```

but above doesn't work, so can any one help me to do this using hold buffer and pattern buffer approach. the advantage i see using this approach is you don't need to count no of occurrence, you can easily provide tag name only in which startdate to be replace.

Data.xml

```
<Data>
        <First>
                        <Name>Micheal</Name>
                        <Account-Validation>
                                <startdate>01011970</startdate>
                                <enddate>01019999</enddate>
                        </Account-Validation>
        </First>
        <Second>
                        <Name>Adam</Name>
                        <Account-Validation>
                                <startdate>01011970</startdate>
                                <enddate>01019999</enddate>
                        </Account-Validation>
        </Second>
        <Third>
                        <Name>Raul</Name>
                        <Account-Validation>
                                <startdate>01011970</startdate>
                                <enddate>01019999</enddate>
                        </Account-Validation>
        </Third>
</Data>
```

Thanks,
Priyank Shah

Comment: Have you considered using XSLT for modifying XML data, as using string replace can often lead to complicated patterns that might not always work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that command does not work is: you selecting address space correctly, but do nothing with it. 's' command must be inside address space.

Example:

```
sed '/<Second>/,/<\/Second>/{s/<startdate>01011970<\/startdate>/<startdate>01011979<\/startdate>/}' Data.xml
```

`{}` braces are optional when you execute only one command like here.